# pandas rolling_sum with center and min_periods

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use the `pandas.rolling_sum` function on a `DataFrame` to sum over a window using whatever data are available for each window (so don't return `NaN` when the window extends beyond the available data).  Here are some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd  # version 0.12.0  (Python 2.7)
df = pd.DataFrame([1]*4+[2]*4,
                  index=pd.date_range('2014-1-1', periods=8, freq='D'),
                  columns=['num'])
df.head()
#             num
# 2014-01-01    1
# 2014-01-02    1
# 2014-01-03    1
# 2014-01-04    1
# 2014-01-05    2
```

Here is the basic, centered rolling sum...

```
pd.rolling_sum(df, 7, center=True)
#             num
# 2014-01-01  NaN
# 2014-01-02  NaN
# 2014-01-03  NaN
# 2014-01-04   10
# 2014-01-05   11
# 2014-01-06  NaN
# 2014-01-07  NaN
# 2014-01-08  NaN
```

I want to eliminate the `NaN` values and use whatever data are available within each window.  My hunch was that the `min_periods` option would take care of this...

```
pd.rolling_sum(df, 7, center=True, min_periods=0)
#             num
# 2014-01-01    4
# 2014-01-02    6
# 2014-01-03    8
# 2014-01-04   10
# 2014-01-05   11
# 2014-01-06  NaN
# 2014-01-07  NaN
# 2014-01-08  NaN
```

This works when the window is not centered using `center=True`, but I'm confused why the last three values are missing.  I was expecting the last three values to be...

```
# 2014-01-06  10
# 2014-01-07   9
# 2014-01-08   8
```

Can anyone explain why `min_periods` is working on the first observations but failing on the last observations when using `center=True` option?  What's the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that pandas first calculates:

```
>>> pd.rolling_sum(df, 7, center=False, min_periods=0)
            num
2014-01-01    1
2014-01-02    2
2014-01-03    3
2014-01-04    4
2014-01-05    6
2014-01-06    8
2014-01-07   10
2014-01-08   11

[8 rows x 1 columns]
```

and then `shift`s the result by `-offset`, where

```
offset = int((window - 1) / 2.)
```

this causes `NaN` values for the last entries even though `min_periods=0`; a work around my be as below:

```
>>> rs = pd.rolling_sum(df, 7, center=True, min_periods=0)
>>> rs.update( pd.rolling_sum(df.iloc[:-7:-1], 7, center=True, min_periods=0) )
>>> rs
            num
2014-01-01    4
2014-01-02    6
2014-01-03    8
2014-01-04   10
2014-01-05   11
2014-01-06   10
2014-01-07    9
2014-01-08    8

[8 rows x 1 columns]
```